# mouseover and mouseout and div with images 1px separated

Tags: jquery

I have div and function mouseover:

```
$('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
    $('#otherdiv').show('slow');
});

$('#otherdiv').mouseout(function(){
    $('#otherdiv').hide('slow');
});
```

but... The `#otherdiv` on show cover `#mydiv` and consists of 5 images `1px` separated from each other. I want to that `#otherdiv` disappear after `mouseout` but I get a blinking.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv').hover(function(){
    $('#otherdiv').stop().show('slow');
}, function(){
    $('#otherdiv').stop().hide('slow');
});
```

[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oneqiy/edit#javascript,html,live)
http://api.jquery.com/hover
http://api.jquery.com/stop

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `stop`:

```
$('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
    $('#otherdiv').stop().show('slow');
});

$('#otherdiv').mouseout(function(){
    $('#otherdiv').stop().hide('slow');
});
```